# Angular 7 http.put() with json body

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to consume a WebAPI resource with Angular 7 HttpClient.  The CURL for the HTTP PUT operation succeeded.

```
curl - X PUT--header 'Content-Type: application/json'--header 'Accept: application/json' - d '%27Reviewed%27'
'https://my.organization/WebAPI/MyServices/Service1/consult/123/800088093313/reviewstatus'
```

I am using the following to do the same but it gave me Http 415 if I use Json.stringfy() or Http 404 if I don't.  Could you help?  Thanks.

```
const requestUrl = this.endpoint + '/consult/' + sta3n.toString() + '/' + consultSid.toString() + '/reviewstatus';
const requestBody = JSON.Stringfy(status);
// const requestBody = {status};
return this._http.put(requestUrl, requestBody);
```

Here is the WebAPI endpoint declaration

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("consult/{sta3n}/{consultSID}/reviewstatus")]
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(String))]
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)]
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)]
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, Type = typeof(Exception))]
public IHttpActionResult SetConsultReviewStatus([FromUri] short sta3n, [FromUri] long consultSID, [FromBody] string status) {
    ...
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **put** method you are not providing **Content-Type** header. Modify http.put line like this

```
return this._http.put(requestUrl, requestBody, , { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } });
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much.